# joining multiple table with conditional statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I Have 3 mysql table like this:

[image]
[image]

based on that table i want to make a table with conditional statement:
if skor from table 3 >= nilai then saran = mayor and minor from table2, else then saran = butuh from table 1 with value more than 0 and concat by bidang. And for nilai =

```
selct((max(skor)-min(skor))*0.25)+min(skor) from table 3
```

so, the result like this:

[image]

how to make this?

Comment: Which language is this?

Comment: the language is mysql

Comment: No, I mean `bidang,kurang,butuh`? Never hard of this terms.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below query:

```
select
NIP,
Bidang,
case when Skor >= ((max(skor)-min(skor))*0.25)+min(skor)
then concat(mayor,',',minor) 
else concat(Butuh,',',Bidang)
end  as Saran
from
(
select table2.*,
table1.Butuh,
table1.Kurang,
table3.Skor
from table2 join table1
on table2.Bidang = table1.Bidang
left join table3 
on table2.NIP = table3.NIP
where table1.Butuh > 0
) tab
```

Comment: i have been try this syntax, but result always null.

Answer (score 0):

assuming that `nilai` just means a global score threshold, you'll basically have to ...

- build a query that aggregates your `nilai` value
- aggregate data from different records into a single string
- join tables and the aggregate query
- select the desired data, applying functions to create the proper output as necessary.

your result will be something along the following lines:

```
select t2.Nip
     , t3.bidang
     , case when t3.skor >= t3disc.nilai then t2.mayor || ', ' || t2.minor else base_1.butuh_agg end
                    saran
  from table_2 t2
  join table_3 t3   on ( t3.Nip = t2.Nip and  t3.bidang = t2.bidang )
  join (
                select t11.bidang
                     , t11.butuh
                        || CASE WHEN t12.butuh IS NOT NULL THEN ', ' || t12.butuh ELSE '' END 
                        || CASE WHEN t13.butuh IS NOT NULL THEN ', ' || t13.butuh ELSE '' END 
                        || CASE WHEN t14.butuh IS NOT NULL THEN ', ' || t14.butuh ELSE '' END 
                        || CASE WHEN t15.butuh IS NOT NULL THEN ', ' || t15.butuh ELSE '' END 
                            butuh_agg
                  from (
                            select t1.bidang
                                 , min(t1.kurang)   kmin
                              from table_1  t1
                          group by t1.bidang
                       ) t11
             left join table_1  t12 on ( t12.bidang = t11.bidang AND t12.kurang = t11.kmin + 1)
             left join table_1  t13 on ( t13.bidang = t11.bidang AND t13.kurang = t11.kmin + 2)
             left join table_1  t14 on ( t14.bidang = t11.bidang AND t14.kurang = t11.kmin + 3)
             left join table_1  t15 on ( t15.bidang = t11.bidang AND t15.kurang = t11.kmin + 4)
        ) base_1   on ( base_1.bidang = t2.bidang )
   join (
               select t31.bidang
                    , t3agg.nilai
                 from table_3  t31
           cross join (
                         select (max(t32.skor) - min(t32.skor)) * 0.25 ) + min(t32.skor)   nilai
                           from table_3 t32
                      ) t3agg
        ) t3disc  on ( t3disc.bidang = t2.bidang )
      ;
```

This suggestion assumes you have at max 4 non-zero values for any given bidang in table 1, that there are no duplicates among these values and that these values are less than or equal 4. otherwise you'd have to resort to a ranking function in your queries.

Comment: syntax error corrected. this code should get you started - i'm a bit rusty on mysql syntax. if you think it's absolutely not helpful, drop a note and i'll remove the answer.